# is it possible to install AFNetworking 2.0 with Restkit

Tags: objective-c, xml, restkit, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I got an news app which fetches news online in XML format in stores it locally in the sqlite dbase.. which is perfect case for restkit.

However, I would like to also fetch xml data manually sometimes (ie and not want to store it in the dbase).. in other words i would like to request it directly with AFNetworking. I like how in [AFNetworking 2.0](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) it does the parsing of xml automatically, and so I want to use that feature.

However, Restkit 2.0 is linked to AFNetworking 1.3.. and so If I add this to my podfile:

```
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.21.0'
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
```

and run a `pod install` I get the following error:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `AFNetworking (~> 1.3.0)` required by `RestKit/Network (0.21.0)`- `AFNetworking (~> 2.0)` required by `Podfile`
```

is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 1.3.0 you have access to `AFXMLRequestOperation` which should fulfil the same goal.

It would be a lot of work to update RestKit to use version 2.0, or to rename so that you could use both versions...

Comment: yes it achieves the same goal.. but with a lot more work (ie it returns an instance of `NSXMLParser`, so I'll still have to implement the `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods)

Comment: Then I'd look at using a normal operation and https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

Comment: interesting library.. however an `XMLDictionaryParser` can only be instantiated by either data, string, or path. How do I make it work with AFNetworking? If i'm going to have to jump back and basically use basic NSUrlrequest stuff to just load the data off a remote server i think it would defeat the purpose of trying to simplify this whole thing.

Comment: oh ok.. found it [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary/pull/11).. it wasn't in the original library but in a fork of it. Thanks! Will update my question with the final code if you don't mind (once i get it running that is)

Comment: What do you mean update RestKit to use version 2.0? Does RestKit support AFNetworking 2.0??

Comment: @Plot, not yet, support for AFN 2 is work-in-progress for RestKit (check the branches on github).

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution could be to just rename the files of afnetworking to af1networking and all the classes/interfaces/constants to AF1xxxx. If we only had namespaces in Objective-C or the AFNetworking guys would have prefixed the new version with AF2...

I think what i describe could be done with a project search and replace in hours.

An Alternative would be to use MKNetworkKit for the networking - it is similiar to afnetworking/afnetworking2 but then you end up having 2 different network libraries and AFNetworking seems to have more effort put into.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [forked](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary) version of **XMLDictionary**, I basically achieved what I wanted to achieve by asking the above question by doing the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFXMLRequestOperation *operation =
[AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request
 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLParser:XMLParser];
    // do stuff with dict        

 failure:failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, 
                   NSError *error, NSXMLParser *XMLParser){

    NSLog(@"somethign weng wrong in fetching news data: %@", 
                 [error localizedDescription]);
}];

[operation start];
```

Credit goes to [Wain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988185/wain) in his [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21496890/766570) comments :)