# Install RestKit without AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I've got an on going project where I'm using `AFNetworking` for request/response layer. And I want to use `RestKit`'s `ObjectMapping` functionality for my `JSON` responses. I tried to install `RestKit` via `cocoapods` but it's going into conflict with already installed `AFNetworking` pod. So I wanted to ask if there any way to install `RestKit`'s `ObjectMapping` module only, and without networking layer?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2028 where is under discussion the possibility to create a branch of RestKit without the AFNetworking dependency. In the meantime you can drop AFNetworking in your Podfile and let RestKit include it; the only downside with this approach is that you are stuck to AFNetworking 1.x.

Comment: yes, that's why I don't want to drop my AFNetworking 2.x

Comment: Unfortunately I'm afraid there's no simple solution. There are hypotheses about renaming in order to use both versions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496696/is-it-possible-to-install-afnetworking-2-0-with-restkit) but they wouldn't be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "RestKit/ObjectMapping" as a Cocoapod dependency for your project without the base networking layer.

Or else check out the work in progress for [RestKit issue 2028](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2028) in https://github.com/oligriffiths/RestKit. It doesn't require AFNetworking at all, but it may need your help getting to a stable state and passing all the tests.

Comment: Consider specifically https://github.com/oligriffiths/RestKit/tree/feature/test_conformance